# Implementing message priority in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I wrote code for implementing message priority java code, but it doesn't work!

These are the code:

**PriorityPartitioner.java**

```
public class PriorityPartitioner implements Partitioner {

    @Override
    public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {
        List<PartitionInfo> partitions = cluster.availablePartitionsForTopic(topic);
        int numPartitions = partitions.size();

        // Get the priority from the message headers
        String priority = getPriorityFromHeaders((byte[]) value);

        // Assign partitions based on priority
        if ("high".equalsIgnoreCase(priority)) {
            return Math.abs("high".hashCode()) % numPartitions;
        } else if ("medium".equalsIgnoreCase(priority)) {
            return Math.abs("medium".hashCode()) % numPartitions;
        } else {
            return Math.abs("low".hashCode()) % numPartitions;
        }
    }

    private String getPriorityFromHeaders(byte[] valueBytes) {
        return new String(valueBytes);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // Cleanup resources, if any
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {


    }
}
```

**PriorityAssignor.java**

```
public class PriorityAssignor implements ConsumerPartitionAssignor {

    private static final int MAX_PRIORITY = 3; // Maximum priority level


    public Map<String, List<TopicPartition>> assign(Map<String, Integer> partitionsPerTopic, Map<String, Subscription> subscriptions) {
        Map<String, List<TopicPartition>> assignment = new HashMap<>();
        List<TopicPartition> partitions = new ArrayList<>();

        // Generate the partitions list
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : partitionsPerTopic.entrySet()) {
            String topic = entry.getKey();
            int numPartitions = entry.getValue();
            for (int i = 0; i < numPartitions; i++) {
                partitions.add(new TopicPartition(topic, i));
            }
        }

        // Sort the partitions based on priority
        Collections.sort(partitions, new PriorityComparator());

        // Group the partitions by consumer ID
        Map<String, List<TopicPartition>> consumerAssignments = new HashMap<>();
        for (String consumerId : subscriptions.keySet()) {
            consumerAssignments.put(consumerId, new ArrayList<>());
        }

        // Assign partitions to consumers in a round-robin fashion
        CircularIterator<String> consumerIterator = new CircularIterator<>(consumerAssignments.keySet());
        for (TopicPartition partition : partitions) {
            String consumerId = consumerIterator.next();
            consumerAssignments.get(consumerId).add(partition);
        }

        // Assign the partitions to the final assignment map
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<TopicPartition>> entry : consumerAssignments.entrySet()) {
            String consumerId = entry.getKey();
            List<TopicPartition> assignedPartitions = entry.getValue();
            assignment.put(consumerId, assignedPartitions);
        }

        return assignment;
    }

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "priority";
    }

    @Override
    public ByteBuffer subscriptionUserData(Set<String> topics) {
        return ConsumerPartitionAssignor.super.subscriptionUserData(topics);
    }

    @Override
    public GroupAssignment assign(Cluster cluster, GroupSubscription groupSubscription) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<RebalanceProtocol> supportedProtocols() {
        return Collections.singletonList(RebalanceProtocol.EAGER);
    }


    private class PriorityComparator implements java.util.Comparator<TopicPartition> {
        @Override
        public int compare(TopicPartition tp1, TopicPartition tp2) {
            int priority1 = getPriorityFromTopic(tp1.topic());
            int priority2 = getPriorityFromTopic(tp2.topic());
            return Integer.compare(priority1, priority2);
        }

        private int getPriorityFromTopic(String topic) {
            // Implement your logic to extract priority from topic name
            // In this example, we assume the priority is encoded in the topic name
            // Modify this method according to your actual topic naming convention
            int priority = Integer.parseInt(topic.substring(topic.lastIndexOf("_") + 1));
            return Math.min(priority, MAX_PRIORITY);
        }
    }


}
```

**KafkaPriorityProducer.java**

```
public class KafkaPriorityProducer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Set up producer properties
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put("partitioner.class", PriorityPartitioner.class.getName());

        // Create a Kafka producer
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

        try {
            while (true) {
            // Produce high-priority message
            String highPriorityMessage = "This is a high-priority message.";
            ProducerRecord<String, String> highPriorityRecord = new ProducerRecord<>("prioritized_topic", "key", highPriorityMessage);
            highPriorityRecord.headers().add("priority", "high".getBytes());
            producer.send(highPriorityRecord, (metadata, exception) -> {
                if (exception == null) {
                    System.out.println("High-priority message sent successfully. Offset: " + metadata.offset());
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Failed to send high-priority message: " + exception.getMessage());
                }
            });

            // Produce low-priority message
            String lowPriorityMessage = "This is a low-priority message.";
            ProducerRecord<String, String> lowPriorityRecord = new ProducerRecord<>("prioritized_topic", "key", lowPriorityMessage);
            lowPriorityRecord.headers().add("priority", "low".getBytes());
            producer.send(lowPriorityRecord, (metadata, exception) -> {
                if (exception == null) {
                    System.out.println("Low-priority message sent successfully. Offset: " + metadata.offset());
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Failed to send low-priority message: " + exception.getMessage());
                }
            });

            // Flush and close the producer
            producer.flush();
        }} catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            producer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**KafkaPriorityConsumer.java**

```
public class KafkaPriorityConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Set up consumer properties
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put("group.id", "my-consumer-group");

        // Create a Kafka consumer
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

        // Subscribe to the prioritized topic
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("prioritized_topic"));

        try {
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));

                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    String key = record.key();
                    String value = record.value();
                    String priority = getPriorityFromHeaders(record.headers().headers("priority"));

                    System.out.println("Received message: Key = " + key + ", Value = " + value + ", Priority = " + priority);
                }

                consumer.commitSync();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
    }

    private static String getPriorityFromHeaders(Iterable<Header> headers) {
        for (Header header : headers) {
            if ("priority".equalsIgnoreCase(header.key())) {
                return new String(header.value());
            }
        }
        return "unknown";
    }
}
```

**After run the code, I receive this error:**
*java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [B (java.lang.String and [B are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at PriorityPartitioner.partition(PriorityPartitioner.java:20)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.partition(KafkaProducer.java:1391)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:1025)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:962)
at KafkaPriorityProducer.main(KafkaPriorityProducer.java:25)*

**How can I solve this error? and is there any mistake in the codes?**

Comment: The `value` passed to `partition` is evidently a `String`, not a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @tgdavies, the `value` Object seems to be already of type `String`, which can be confirmed by using `instanceof` operator.